# How to delete a line containing pattern which is first found after a specific pattern

Tags: text-processing

I am writting a shell script to delete an entry from a specific group.
eg: file name is `dest.xml`

```
<domain id="1" group_name="group1">
    <node id="ABC">
    <node id="PQR">
    <node id="XYZ">
</domain>
<domain id="2" group_name="group2">
    <node id="PQR">
    <node id="XYZ">
</domain>
<domain id="3" group_name="group3">
    <node id="ABC">
    <node id="PQR">
 </domain>
```

I want to delete an entry from above file (filename is dest.xml) with `node id="PQR"` from `group_name="group1"` (it should not get deleted from group2 and group3).
I can do it by reading a file sequentially n then delete it from a specific group. But if the file is to large (>10k lines) then it takes time.

Is there any simple way to this this?

Comment: Sure, but better gives a known file type, that one is unknown.

Comment: That is not valid XML.

Comment: @jordanm its probably a snippet and it doesn't matter for the question of the OP.

Comment: Is this XML? If so, use an XML parser. If this is some ad-hoc vaguely XML-like syntax, awk as proposed by Stephane is fine.

Comment: I removed the [tag:xml] tag since it's clearly not XML.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk` if the format doesn't diverge from the sample you provided:

```
awk -F'[<>="[:blank:]]+' '
  $2 == "domain" {group = $(NF-1)}
  !(group == "group1" && $2 == "node" && $(NF-1) == "PQR")
  ' < dest.xml > new-dest.xml
```

to remove that "PQR" node in the "group1" domain.

```
$ diff -u dest.xml new-dest.xml
--- dest.xml    2013-02-22 07:01:48.732227421 +0000
+++ new-dest.xml        2013-02-22 07:02:16.111512820 +0000
@@ -1,6 +1,5 @@
 <domain id="1" group_name="group1">
     <node id="ABC">
-    <node id="PQR">
     <node id="XYZ">
 </domain>
 <domain id="2" group_name="group2">
```

If you mean you wish to remove that node from the XML file in place, then that's not really possible. You'd need at least to rewrite the part that is after that node to shift the data as many bytes backward.

Alternatively, you could replace that node with blanks which would mean you could get away with replacing those bytes only.

```
perl -ne '
  if (/<domain.*group_name="(.*?)"/) {
    $in = $1 eq "group1"
  } elsif ($in && /<node id="PQR"/) {
    s/./ /g;
    seek STDOUT,tell(STDIN)-length$_,0;
    print
  }' < dest.xml 1<> dest.xml
```

Add a `;exit` after the `print` above if there's only one such node and you want to stop processing as soon as you've found it.

Comment: Hi Stephane, I am new to unix shell scripts. I tried running this command but its not working for me. Can you please interpret the above command which is missing my file name "dest".

Comment: @PravinNagare, just append your file name to this command line (separated by a space of course).

Comment: Hi, I appended file name after command seperated by space awk -F'[<>="[:blank:]]+' '
  $2 == "domain" {group = $(NF-1)}
  !(group == "group1" && $2 == "node" && $(NF-1) == "PQR")' dest.xml but its not working for me. Its just displaying the whole file as it is.

Comment: @PravinNagare, You mean it's not removing the PQR node in the first domain?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas yes, Its not removing PQR node from group1.

Comment: @PravinNagare, it works with the sample you provided with a POSIX awk. If you're on Solaris, use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk. See also my updated answer for alternatives.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks! /usr/xpg4/bin/awk is working for me. But when I put this in a script(script.sh) and use variables instead of direct value then its not working.  #!/bin/ksh
gp_name=group1
entry=PQR

/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F'[<>="[:blank:]]+' '
  $2 == "domain" {group = $(NF-1)}
  !(group == "$gp_name" && $2 == "node" && $(NF-1) == "$entry")
  ' < dest.xml > new-dest.xml   It is just copying dest.xml to new-dest.xml. where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick python script, do not know if it's simple enough.

Place this script in the same folder with your `dest.xml`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
FILENAME = 'dest.xml'
GROUPNAME = 'group1'
NODEID = 'PQR'

with open(FILENAME) as f:
    in_group = False
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        group_pattern = 'group_name="{0}">'.format(GROUPNAME)
        end_group_pattern = '</domain>'
        node_pattern = '<node id="{0}">'.format(NODEID)
        if re.search(group_pattern, line):
            in_group = True
        if re.search(end_group_pattern, line):
            in_group = False
        if re.search(node_pattern, line) and in_group:
            pass
        else:
            print line
```

And now is the awk version.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    GROUPNAME = "group1"
    NODEID = "PQR"
    in_group = 0
    group_pattern =  ".*group_name=\"" GROUPNAME "\""
    end_group_pattern = "</domain>"
    node_pattern = "<node id=\"" NODEID "\">"
}
$0 ~ group_pattern {
   in_group = 1
}
$0 !~ node_pattern || in_group == 0 {
    print $0
}
$0 ~ end_group_pattern {
    in_group = 0
}
```

Run this awk script with argument is your file name `dest.xml`. Seem that it's simpler than the python version.